# Explanatory form のです used in two consecutive sentences

Tags: explanatory-の

I am learning the explanatory form のです. My book gives the example:

> ケーキはもうないのです。犬がぜんぶ食べたのです。
>
> There is no more cake. That's because the dog ate everything.

I don’t understand why they use the explanatory form in both sentences, I would think it is used only in the last one. All the other examples I have found work that way.

Can anyone confirm that this example is good, and explain why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the first sentence looks fairly unnatural to me if this is everything in the conversation. You have to say ケーキがなくなってしまいました or something if this is the first sentence in a conversation.

However, this may be valid if there is enough context before this, for example:

> A: 昨日買ったケーキを持ってきてくれ。
> B: 申し訳ありません、ケーキはもうないのです。犬がぜんぶ食べたのです。

Now ケーキはもうない works as the reason for saying "I'm sorry", so the use of explanatory-の in that position is also natural. (As an aside, んです is much more common than のです in speech, even in formal settings.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I learned a lot thanks to you!

After further thought, I think the context of those sentences is:
the guy leaves some cake on a table (for example), expecting to eat it later. He leaves the room to do something, and comes back a bit later to eat the cake, but it has disappeared.
So first he expresses his surprise (my book says のです can be used to express surprise), and in a second time he understands what happened and explains it. He's talking to himself the whole time...

In that case, do you think the first sentence still sounds unnatural?